# How to restrict HomeKit accessory for other iOS applications

Tags: ios, homekit, ios-homekit

We have created the iOS application using HomeKit framework for our accessory. Is there any way to restrict other developers or other iOS application to use accessory?

If anyway we implement it is Apple approve for the same?

Comment: The hole idea behind home kit is that all accessories can be controlled via one API. Thus making apps possible that only talk to this API, like Siri. If you want to restrict you accessory than you are already looking at the idea of HomeKit in the wrong way.

Comment: I concur with @rckoenes. When a HomeKit capable accessory is paired, it's being added to a HomeKit DB which is shared among devices (via iCloud sync) and other apps that are allowed to access the homekit database. From your iOS app: you can always add filters to remove other homekit capable accessories and only show your desired accessory for pairing availability, but that doesn't (read shouldn't) restrict your accessory to be discovered and controlled using HomeKit library api used by other 3rd party apps with permission.